# Add images to ListView dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my program I have a `listview` where I can add images from my folder.

The selected image should be displayed big in the programm.

Right now I can only display the image I just opened from my folder.

My question is, how can I add images to the `listview` and display the selected image?

I know that I need a variable for the selected Image and an observable collection for my images in the `listview`.

My Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="GridLoadedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command ="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownCommnad}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonUpCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Image x:Name="_image" Margin="10" Source="{Binding CurrentImage.ImagePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MaxHeight="40"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SaveCommand = new ViewModelBase(this.saveFile);
    CropCommand = new ViewModelBase(this.Croping);
    ResizeCommand = new ViewModelBase(this.Resize);
    Image = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
}
```

Open

```
 ICommand _openCommand;
    public ICommand OpenCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_openCommand == null)
            {
                _openCommand = new ViewModelBase(param => Open());
            }
            return _openCommand;
        }
    }
    private void Open()
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog open = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        open.DefaultExt = (".png");
        open.Filter = "JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(open.FileName);
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();
        this.currentImage.ImagePath = myBitmapImage;           
    }
```

ImageModel

```
 BitmapSource imagePath;
    public BitmapSource ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set
        {
            imagePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }
```

Maybe my approach is wrong? Advices are welcomed since I am new to MVVM and WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ImageModel should have an Image property that is either of type string, Uri or ImageSource, e.g.

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
}
```

The collection property in your MainViewModel should better be named `Images` instead of `Image`, and there should be a `CurrentImage` property:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> Images { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();

    private ImageModel currentImage;
    public ImageModel CurrentImage
    {
        get { return currentImage; }
        set
        {
            currentImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentImage)));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you bind a ListView or ListBox's `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`, and declare its `ItemTemplate` like this (where the StackPanel might be redundant):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentImage}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" MaxHeight="40" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The selected image may now be shown in another Image element like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage.Image}"/>
```

When opening an image file, you should also add it to the Images collection, like this:

```
if ((bool)open.ShowDialog())
{
    var item = new ImageModel
    {
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(open.FileName))
    };

    Images.Add(item);
    CurrentImage = item;
}
```

Comment: In my ImageModel I have a Image property of type BitmapSource. See my edited Question. Would this work too? Otherwise thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. The property can be of any type that can directly be assigned to the Image.Source property, or be converted by built-in type conversion, like string, Uri or byte[]. Besides that, you may always also use a Binding Converter.

Comment: This really helped me. But now when I open an image for the second time it replaces the first image in the listview, which is inconvenient.

Comment: Not sure what that means. With the code above, opening an image file a second time should result in having two identical images in the list.

Comment: My bad I didn't explain it well. What I meant is when I open a second image it replaces the first image in the listview and then I have the same image twice.

Comment: That won't happen if you implement it as shown in the answer. Note however that a DataTemplate tag was missing in the XAML. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I implemented it exactly like this, maybe the error is somewhere else. But anyways thank for the help!

Comment: I forgot to ask what does this line do? var item = new ImageModel
    {
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(open.FileName))
    };
Or maybe I should ask why did you do it like that? I'm asking so I can understand it better and learn from it.

Comment: That's basic C#. It creates a new ImageModel instance, and assigns a newly created BitmapImage to its Image property.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. So basically I can access to my ImageModel with this